# grails asset pipeline plugin

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I have read the documentation of Grails asset pipeline plugin so I started implementing it in a sample grails project built in `2.2.3`. I installed the asset pipeline plugin version `1.7.1`. My requirement is to include `jquery.ui.min.js` in my gsp file so I included by using the tag

`<asset:javascript src="jquery-ui.min.js"/>`.

Also, in my Config.groovy, I have made the following entry

`grails.assets.bundle=true`.

The problem which I am facing is that I'm unable to access the jquery.ui.min.js in my gsp file. Pease tell me what am I missing and how should I proceed with it as I could not get any valid solutions for my query??

Comment: Can you also add how the manifest is setup?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reference a different file:

```
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

And `application.js` contains:

```
//= require jquery-ui.min
```

at the top of the file (make sure there isn't any blank lines above that line, other comment lines are ok) to load your lib. See http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#directives

This answer is a guess based on what Grails 2.4 gives me out of the box. FYI, the auto-generated `application.js` contains:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js.
//
// Any JavaScript file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// You're free to add application-wide JavaScript to this file, but it's generally better 
// to create separate JavaScript files as needed.
//
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

Comment: in addition, the jquery-ui.min.js then should reside in the assets/javascript directory.  If you have many other libraries, I would recommend having a js-lib or lib at the same level as javascript and reference it in the manifest as //= require ../lib/jquery-ui/*.js